# Reducing Time for Nested For Loops in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I am attempting to extract some information from a data set that is about 178,000 lines long. I have a data frame with about 9 variables but am only using 3 of them for this portion. A very small subset of this data might look something like this:

```
date <- as.Date(c("2016-09-17", "2016-09-14", "2016-09-17", "2016-09-13","2016-09-17"))
idnum <- c("1", "2", "1", "1", "1")
hour <- round(as.numeric(c("15.75", "16.34", "16.12", "15.53", "17.10")), digits = 2)

all <- data.frame(date, idnum, hour)
```

Giving this:

```
   date      idnum     hour
2016-09-17     1      15.75
2016-09-14     2      16.34
2016-09-17     1      16.12
2016-09-13     1      15.53
2016-09-17     1      17.10
```

My goal is to determine the number of uses that are within an hour for each ID on each date (I called that variable close). In the end my data should look like this:

```
   date      idnum     hour    close
2016-09-17     1      15.75      1
2016-09-14     2      16.34      0
2016-09-17     1      16.12      2
2016-09-13     1      15.53      0
2016-09-17     1      17.10      1
```

I have gotten the following code to work for this small data set

```
all$close <- 0
m <- 1

for (i in m:nrow(all)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(all)) {
        if(i != j & all$date[i] == all$date[j] & all$idnum[i] == idnum[j] 
          & abs(all$hour[i] - all$hour[j]) <= 1) {
           all$close[i] <- all$close[i] + 1                              
        } else {
          all$close[i] <- all$close[i]
        }
    }
    m = m + 1
}
```

However, as soon as I expand this to a larger number of rows, the run time is really long. Is there a more efficient way to do this in `r`?

Comment: Without looking more closely, you will want to use `&&` instead of `&` in your `if` conditions. See `help("&&")` for a comparison of these operators. You may also look at using `seq_along` to simplify some of your indexing.

Comment: You need to better define "within one hour". What is the expected output for 16:00, 16:45, 17:30? You don't want to use a `for` loop. If you use a loop you should first sort your data.frame by datetime and make use of the sorting.

Comment: Roland - by within one hour I mean an hour before and after. If the ID's and Dates are the same, I would expect output to be 1, 2, and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorted vector `x`, `findInterval(x+1, x) - findInterval(x-1, x)` gives the number of observations that falls within the specified interval `(x[i]-1, x[i]+1)` for each observation `x[i]`.

```
library(dplyr)     
all %>% 
  group_by(idnum, date) %>%
  arrange(hour) %>% 
  mutate(close1 = findInterval(hour+1, hour) - findInterval(hour-1, hour) - 1)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: idnum, date [3]

#        date  idnum  hour close
#       <date> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2016-09-17      1 15.75     1
# 2 2016-09-14      2 16.34     0
# 3 2016-09-17      1 16.12     2
# 4 2016-09-13      1 15.53     0
# 5 2016-09-17      1 17.10     1
```

For comparison,

```
set.seed(1234)
date <- as.Date("2016-1-1") + sample(1:1000, 10000, TRUE)
idnum <- sample(1:100, 1e4, TRUE)
hour <- sample(0:239, 10000, TRUE)/10
all <- data.frame(date, idnum, hour)

system.time(
all <- all %>% 
  group_by(idnum, date) %>%
  arrange(hour) %>% 
  mutate(close1 = findInterval(hour+1, hour) - findInterval(hour-1, hour) - 1)
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.25    0.00    0.27
```